# jQuery sort() is not sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting

I want to sort a li within divs alphabetical by jQuery

At the moment, something indefinable happens. Is apparently sorted without a pattern.

Here is a snippet of my html

```
<ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front">
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-149" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Great Britain</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-128" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Austria</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-150" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Nigeria</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-169" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Morocco</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-132" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Turkey</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-133" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Romania</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-134" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Belgium</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-135" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Netherlands</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-136" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Luxembourg</div>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

the js:

```
var $lis = $('.ui-menu-item');
var alphabeticallyOrderedLis = $lis.sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).find("div").text() > $(b).find("div").text();
});
$(".ui-autocomplete").html(alphabeticallyOrderedLis);
```

But please visit the fiddle to check it on your own: https://jsfiddle.net/the_taeq/jwx1w729/

Am I really that stupid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(a).find("div").text().localeCompare($(b).find("div").text());
```

You need to properly compare the string values.  Strings do not play nicely with `<` or `>` typically.

Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Answer (score 1):

Use this jquery code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $list = $("#ui-id-1");

  $list.children().detach().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
  }).appendTo($list);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have space in the string at position 0 then this code work for me

```
$(a).find("div").text().trim().charAt(0).toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).find("div").text().trim().charAt(0).toUpperCase());
```